# Passing res wrapped in object into callback fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, binding

I have a temporary server that looks like this:

```js
import http from 'http'

export default function tempServer(
  port: number
): Promise<{ req: http.IncomingMessage; res: http.ServerResponse }> {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const server = http
      .createServer(function (req, res) {
        resolve({ req, res })

        // This works

        // res.write('Hey!')
        // res.end()

        server.close()
      })
      .listen(port)
  })
}
```

And I am trying to manipulate `res` by calling `res.write` in another function:

```js
function () {
    const server = tempServer(parseInt(process.env.AUTH_PORT) || 5671)

    return server.then(({req, res}) => {
       const data = url.parse(req.url, true).query

       ...

       res.write('Error: ' + data.error)
       res.end()
       
       ...

    })
}
```

The result is that `res.write` and `res.write` have no effect. I am sure the issue has something to do with contexts and bindings but I am having trouble going about it. Anyone willing to indulge me?

Comment: What do you mean `res.end` and `res.write` have no effect? It works for me. I can use `res.write` send data to client.

Comment: For some reason, `res.write` will not send data back to the client and `res.end` will not close the connection. Maybe I'm making a mistake on my end, I'll double check.